# Is it possible to set the Expires/Max-Age of an existing cookie with the Set-Cookie header?

Tags: cookies, http-headers

I'm trying to have the expiration of an existing cookie on a site update from "Session" to some date in the future using the Set-Cookie header.

I believe my issue has to do with limitations on how browsers interpret the Path directive on the Set-Cookie header but I'm not sure nor can I find a use case quite like mine.

Example use case:

Browser navigates to:

```
GET / HTTP/2
Host: example.com
```

Server replies:

```
HTTP/2 200
set-cookie: PHPSESSID=abcd; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
```

Browser performs action and navigates to:

```
POST /some/path HTTP/2
Cookie: PHPSESSID=abcd;...
```

Server replies:

```
HTTP/2 302
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dcba; expires=Mon, 17-Aug-2020 19:08:24 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; path=/
Location: /somewhere-else
```

All following requests from the browser contain the updated cookie value:

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=dcba;...
```

Yet, upon inspecting the cookies with the dev tools (or simply closing the browser) I noticed that the Expires/Max-Age of the cookie is still "Session" (tried on Chrome and Firefox).

Is being able to update the value but not the expiration of a cookie through a Set-Cookie header a known/expected behavior? Or is there perhaps something wrong with how it's formed?

Answer (score 3):

For any that come across this question/issue:

I discovered(?) that with each Set-Cookie header received: the browser will update the Expiration/Max-Age of that cookie to "Session" if it is absent but will not update other directive values to anything else if they are absent (such as the `Secure` flag or the value for `SameSite`).

This revealed that the underlying issue was that, in the next page, there was a request happening with the `Set-Cookie` header but did not have any value for the `expires/Max-Age` directives thus resetting the expiration to "Session", making the solution to **ensure every `Set-Cookie` response header has a deliberate value (or absence) for the `expires` and/or `Max-Age` directive**.

Explained with raw http, continuing the example in the question:

If the response for say an ajax request comes back with:

```
HTTP/2 200
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=efgh; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
```

Then the browser will update the cookie's value and set its expiration from "17-Aug-2020 19:08:24 GMT" to "Session".

Making the solution, as mentioned before, to ensure that the response contains the correct (or deliberate) value for the `expires` or `Max-Age` directive, so the correct response for the ajax call that accidentally set the expiration to "Session" in the example above would be something like:

```
HTTP/2 200
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=efgh; expires=Mon, 17-Aug-2020 19:08:24 GMT; Max-Age=7775900; Path=/
```